# Toss a fair coin four times independently. Let X be the number of heads minus the number of tails. Find the distribution of X.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This is what I have right now:

$$
\begin{array}{l|c} %l/c/r = left-align/centre/right-align | for a vertical bar
\mathrm{Outcome} & X = \mbox{#heads} - \mbox{#tails}\\\hline
HHHH     & 4  \\
HHHT     & 2  \\
HHTH     & 2  \\
HHTT     & 0  \\
HTHH     & 2  \\
HTHT    & 0  \\
HTTT     & -2  \\
THHH     & 2 \\
THHT      & 0\\
THTH     & 0  \\
THTT    & -2  \\
TTHH    & 0  \\
TTHT     & -2 \\
TTTH     & -2  \\
TTTT    & -4  \\
\\
\end{array}
$$

Then distribution function
$$
F(x)= P(X\leq x) = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x < -4, \\
  \frac{1}{15}, & \text{if }  -4 \leq x < -2 \\
  \frac{1}{3}, & \text{if }  -2 \leq x < 0 \\
  \frac{3}{5}, & \text{if }  0 \leq x < 2 \\
  \frac{14}{15} & \text{if }  2 \leq x < 4\\
  1, & \text{if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}
$$
Do I have this right?

Comment: There should be 16 outcomes.  You missed one.  HTTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about one outcome: $\color{red}{HTTH}$.

The corrected list is then

$$
\begin{array}{l|c} %l/c/r = left-align/centre/right-align | for a vertical bar
\mathrm{Outcome} & X = \mbox{#heads} - \mbox{#tails}\\\hline
HHHH     & 4  \\
HHHT     & 2  \\
HHTH     & 2  \\
HHTT     & 0  \\
HTHH     & 2  \\
HTHT    & 0  \\
\color{red}{HTTH}& 0\\
HTTT     & -2  \\
THHH     & 2 \\
THHT      & 0\\
THTH     & 0  \\
THTT    & -2  \\
TTHH    & 0  \\
TTHT     & -2 \\
TTTH     & -2  \\
TTTT    & -4  \\
\\
\end{array}
$$

The probabilities are equal: $\frac1{16}$ but not $\frac1{15}$.

Now, we can redo the cdf:

$$
F(x)= P(X\leq x) = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } x < -4, \\
  \frac{1}{16}, & \text{if }  -4 \leq x < -2 \\
  \frac{5}{16}, & \text{if }  -2 \leq x < 0 \\
  \frac{11}{16}, & \text{if }  0 \leq x < 2 \\
  \frac{15}{16} & \text{if }  2 \leq x < 4\\
  \frac{16}{16}, & \text{if } x \geq 4
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Almost, but not quite.

Each of the 4 coins can be one of two possibilities: either be heads or tails, so there are $2^4 = 16$ different ways for the four fair coins, not 15. When you make a list, be sure to check that you didn't leave out any case.

Actually, there are ways to make sure you are correct.

$x < -4$ : $0$. The reason is obvious, as there cannot be more than 4 tails.

$-4 \leq x < -2$ : $\frac{1}{16}$. There is only one case: $TTTT$.

$ -2 \leq x < 0$ : $\frac{5}{16}$. There are 4 extra ways: as you can place the "$H$" in 4 positions. $HTTT$, $THTT$, $TTHT$, and $TTTH$.

$0 \leq x <2$ : $\frac{11}{16}$. We place the $H$ in one of 4 spots, and the other $H$ in one of the other 3. Be careful! We have to divide by 2, as the heads are indistinguishable, so $H_1H_2T_3T_4$ is the same as $H_2H_1T_3T_4$. $\frac{3\cdot4}{2}= 6$, and $5+6 = 11$.

$2 \leq x <4$ : $\frac{15}{16}$ We do the same thing as $ -2 \leq x < 0$.

And finally, $ x \geq 4 $. Obviously, this is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from missing one of the sixteen outcomes (HTTH), you do have the right idea.

We can also do it thusly:

> The count of heads is binomially distributed, and the count of tails is complementary (they add to 4), so we can use the binomial distribution, $\mathcal{Bin}(4,1/2)$, to obtain the distribution of the difference.
>
> $$\def\P{\operatorname{\sf P}} \begin{align}\P(H-T=-4) ~&=~ \P(H=0, T=4) &= 1/16\\[1ex]\P(H-T=-2) ~&=~ \P(H=1, T=3) &= 4/16\\[1ex]\P(H-T=\;0\;) ~&=~ \P(H=2,T=2) &= 6/16\\[1ex]\P(H-T=\;2\;) ~&=~ \P(H=3, T=1) &= 4/16\\[1ex]\P(H-T=\;4\;) ~&=~ \P(H=4, T=0) &= 1/16\end{align}$$